# download jsp project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have jsp from server-side. When i make ajax call with jquery from client-side there is response with empty spaces which is generated by scriptlet from JSP.

JSP in its turn connects to database and retrieves login if exists and sends response - a single word.

If there is no such row it does not do anything, so the response is almost empty (when I say empty I mean there are empty spaces, tabs and line drops).

So how to remove those absolutely empty spaces in response.

The code is

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
i = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $.post("checkLogin.jsp",
            {
              login: $('input').val(),

            },
            function(data,status){
                    $('#error').html(data.length);
            });
 });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 Enter your name: <input id='input' type="text">

 <p style="background-color: red;" id="error"></p>
 </body>
 </html>`
```

Comment: If you use maven, once downloaded the dependencies are stored in your local m2 repository so you can work offline.

Comment: maven? How to use it. Just create a maven project and it works as a regular j2ee project?

Comment: When you are at home, just select in Maven settings to work offline. It will then use the locally saved jar files in m2 repository(There is a .m2 folder in linux).

Comment: but what is called that folder in windows

Comment: *it requires internet access to get dependencies installed* what do you mean  exactly by **it**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Maven, once run it will install all the required dependencies in your .m2(C:\Users\username) folder.

You can use the following for your reference.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/